# Symbolic function input non-symbolic parameters

Tags: matlab, function, parameters

I need to define a function that returns a symbolic matrix (sym). It takes 4 input parameters- 2 symbolic matrices, and 2 integers. How do I do that?

This is what I was trying to do-

```
%my function
function F = matrix(F, F4, i, j)

...

F=...;

end

%calling it in a different file

syms M1;
M1 = ...;

syms M2;
M2 = ...;

syms M3;
M3 = matrix(M1,M2,1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this easy test;

```
function L = test(A,B,c,d)
syms tmp1 tmp2

tmp1 = c;
tmp2 = d;

L = tmp1*A + tmp2*B;

end
```

where `A` and `B` are already symbolic matrices.